# Google calendar security

Tags: google

What security measure has Google calendar offered us when I can view the calendar of people in my circle?

Yeterday i was able to view my colleague's calendar by just entering his name from the circles' list in my calendar page.Does that make any sense?

Comment: if he shared the calendar, then yes. This is more of a Google app configuration question than an InfoSec question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the level of details shared with other people. There is [detailed information](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en) about this provided by Google.

I guess that in the case of your acquaintance, he or she shared details with you, circles or made the calendar public.